# Help needed on sorting excel column value

Tags: excel, sorting, vba

I want to take columns from an excel worksheet and then sort them.  Let say I have a column A with value a,b,c,d,e,f and  another column B with value 3,5,6,1,5,6. I want to sort both columns A and B using the values of column B. I’m not sound in VBA. So I got stuck to get the two column and sort them out from excel sheet. Bubble sort is enough for me right now.

[image]

I wanna sort Column A and B using value of B

Comment: data>sort.  Or do you need to do it in vba?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should do it:

```
Range("A2:B10").Select
Selection.Sort Key1:=Range("B:B"), Order1:=xlAscending
```

To place sorted column A values in column C (leaving A undisturbed):

```
Range("C2:C10").Value = Range("A2:A10").Value
Range("B2:C10").Select
Selection.Sort Key1:=Range("B:B"), Order1:=xlAscending
```

Comment: Dim ws As Worksheet
Set ws = Worksheets("PartsData")
ws.Range ("A1:B2") 
not working somehow … getting error

Comment: @rokonoid I'm not sure what you're referring to here. What's that declaration for?

Comment: thanks. it working nice.. how about if I wanna show sort result in another column.. thanks

Comment: sure!! actually i didn't get it yet... can we chat..? anm_brr@yahoo.com